# Inserting and updating records in a table with csv file

Tags: mysql, sql-server, csv

I find myself performing an SP which takes a csv file to load a TMP table and according to the records reported in the file, performs the insertion or update of records in a final table and the following is happening to me:

When the table is completely empty I insert the records, which is correct, but the moment the file that is loaded has some of the records and inserts and a new record not inserted, I am only updating the records that are already Inserted And I do not insert the new record.

I then share what I am doing, so that they help me by indicating that I am doing wrong.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT A.placa,
                      A.id_rom
               FROM   tbl_certi_gnv AS A,
                      #importsuic AS B
               WHERE  A.placa = B.r_placa
                      AND A.id_rom = B.r_id_rom)
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tbl_certi_gnv
                  (placa,
                   id_rom,
                   nit_distribuidor,
                   nit_taller_conv,
                   nit_certificador,
                   fecha_certificacion_inicial,
                   fecha_ultima_revision,
                   fecha_proxima_revision,
                   boton_habilitado,
                   ciudad,
                   usuario_ingresa_datos,
                   fecha_procesamiento)
      SELECT r_placa,
             r_id_rom,
             d_nit_distribuidor,
             d_nit_taller_conv,
             d_nit_certificador,
             f_fecha_certificacion_inicial,
             f_fecha_ultima_revision,
             f_fecha_proxima_revision,
             d_boton_habilitado,
             r_ciudad,
             d_usuario_ingresa_datos,
             Getdate()
      FROM   #importsuic
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      UPDATE tbl_certi_gnv
      SET    fecha_proxima_revision = B.f_fecha_proxima_revision,
             fecha_procesamiento = Getdate()
      FROM   tbl_certi_gnv AS A,
             #importsuic AS B
      WHERE  A.placa = B.r_placa
             AND A.id_rom = B.r_id_rom

      PRINT 'ENTRA A ACTUALIZAR'
  END
```

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server ?

Comment: The reason you'd only be updating is because the exists clause would be false (records do exist). My guess is you want to upsert. In SQL Server, you can use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your logic checks if any of the rows exists, and if it does, it goes to the update part. You need to do something like this:

```
  UPDATE tbl_certi_gnv
  SET    fecha_proxima_revision = B.f_fecha_proxima_revision,
         fecha_procesamiento = Getdate()
  FROM   tbl_certi_gnv AS A,
         #importsuic AS B
  WHERE  A.placa = B.r_placa
         AND A.id_rom = B.r_id_rom
```

And then insert the rows that are missing:

```
  INSERT INTO tbl_certi_gnv
              (placa,
               id_rom,
               nit_distribuidor,
               nit_taller_conv,
               nit_certificador,
               fecha_certificacion_inicial,
               fecha_ultima_revision,
               fecha_proxima_revision,
               boton_habilitado,
               ciudad,
               usuario_ingresa_datos,
               fecha_procesamiento)
  SELECT r_placa,
         r_id_rom,
         d_nit_distribuidor,
         d_nit_taller_conv,
         d_nit_certificador,
         f_fecha_certificacion_inicial,
         f_fecha_ultima_revision,
         f_fecha_proxima_revision,
         d_boton_habilitado,
         r_ciudad,
         d_usuario_ingresa_datos,
         Getdate()
  FROM   #importsuic B
  WHERE  not exists (
           select 1
           FROM   tbl_certi_gnv AS A
           WHERE  A.placa = B.r_placa
                  AND A.id_rom = B.r_id_rom)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use **[merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)** for this.

Like this:

```
merge tbl_certi_gnv      as target
  using #importsuic as source
     on   target.placa =  source.placa 
      and target.id_rom = source.id_rom
      when not matched by target 
        then insert (placa, id_rom, nit_distribuidor, nit_taller_conv, nit_certificador, fecha_certificacion_inicial
               , fecha_ultima_revision, fecha_proxima_revision, boton_habilitado, ciudad, usuario_ingresa_datos, fecha_procesamiento) 
        values (source.r_placa, source.r_id_rom, source.d_nit_distribuidor, source.d_nit_taller_conv, source.d_nit_certificador
              , source.f_fecha_certificacion_inicial, source.f_fecha_ultima_revision, source.f_fecha_proxima_revision
              , source.d_boton_habilitado, source.r_ciudad, source.d_usuario_ingresa_datos, Getdate())
      when matched by target 
        then update 
          set target.fecha_proxima_revision = source.f_fecha_proxima_revision
               ,target.fecha_procesamiento = Getdate();
```